# Cannot configure an authenticator for method [KEYCLOAK]

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak, authenticator

```
` <security-constraint>
           <web-resource-collection>
              <web-resource-name>myapp</web-resource-name>
              <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
          </web-resource-collection>
          <auth-constraint>
              <role-name>admin</role-name>
          </auth-constraint>

      </security-constraint>
              <security-role>
          <role-name>admin</role-name>
      </security-role>

      <login-config>
          <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
         <realm-name>TESTAPP</realm-name>
      </login-config>`
```

I am trying to secure my web application deployed on tomcat with redhat SSO.. But when I deploy my application on the Linux box and start the tomcat server, I get the below error,

02-Apr-2020 11:14:26.046 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig Cannot configure an authenticator for method [KEYCLOAK]
02-Apr-2020 11:14:26.047 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)

When I go to web.xml and change the authentication method from KEYCLOAK to BASIC, I'm able to start the application but on entering the web address, instead of redirecting to the SSO page, Iget a small popup for user anme and address.Can anyone think what's going on?

Comment: Did you ever solved this issue? I'm running into the same problem... No resource for this issue

My assumption is that I did not install the Keycloak Adapters properly into the Tomcat... but I followed the step 3 times already and still same issue

${tomcat-home}/lib/ Dropped the 10-12 adapter jar files in there

Comment: I do not remember the exact fix. I had to check all the redirect URIs and craeted a realm role and assigned the usergroup with the user that role. In place of admin, I added the "realm-role"

Comment: In my case, I forgot to put the KeycloakAuthenticatorValve in META-INF/context.xml: <Valve className="org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve"/>